# Check status of build request sent by "buildbot sendchange" command

Tags: buildbot

I have a case where I am able to successfully trigger a build in buildbot by using sendchange command. While this works, I am unable to find a command to check if the build that was triggered by sendchange has finished.

Is there a way to achieve this in buildbot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since buildbot is asynchronous, you will need to poll the builder for builds that match your sendchange, and then poll that build for build status.  Using e.g. python, it's fairly trivial using requests (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) to retrieve a build's json and examine the state from the command line.

The "API" in this case is to use requests.get(url).json() and traverse the buildbot builds looking for your change request.  The buildbot json is documented in the "REST API" section of the docs (http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/developer/rest.html), you'll have to hunt to figure out how change requests are stored.

Here's some code that will get you started:

```
import pprint, requests

def get_url_base(serv,port):
    return 'http://%(serv)s:%(port)d' % locals()

def get_bldr_json(serv,port,bldr):
    url = 'http://%(serv)s:%(port)d/json/builders/%(bldr)s' % locals()
    print "get_bldr_json: %s ..." % url
    jdata = requests.get(url).json()
    print "DEBUG: get_bldr_json:", pprint.pformat(jdata)
    return jdata

def get_bld_json(serv,port,bldr,bnum):
    url = 'http://%(serv)s:%(port)d/json/builders/%(bldr)s/builds/%(bnum)s' % locals()
    print "get_bld_json: %s ..." % url
    jdata = requests.get(url).json()
    print "DEBUG: get_bld_json:", pprint.pformat(jdata)
    return jdata

# you'll have to set these values for your buildbot
serv, port, bldr = ('hexbotserver', 8010, 'buildername')

jdata = get_bldr_json(serv,port,bldr)

for bnum in jdata['cachedBuilds']:
    jdata = get_bld_json(serv,port,bldr,bnum)
    print "build properties:"
    pprint.pprint(dict(jdata)['properties'])
```

Comment: What's the API to do this portion - "you will need to poll the builder for builds that match your sendchange" ... I couldn't find it in Buildbot documentation